# Button Not Displayed in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am learning Kivy, the button is not displayed in the Kivy Screen. I am unable to find the issue. My Python version is 3.5.3

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass


class TheLabApp(App):
    pass


TheLabApp().run()
```

```
MainWidget:

<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "Hello"
        size: "40dp", "40dp"
        pos: "100dp", "200dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your .kv file starts with the prefix 'TheLab', from the [Pong Game Tutorial](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html):

> COMMON ERROR: The name of the kv file, e.g. pong.kv, must match the name of the app, e.g. PongApp (the part before the App ending)

2. Add the build method to your App class:

   ```
    class TheLabApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return MainWidget()
   ```

Edit: A full working example:

*main.py

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


    class MainWidget(Widget):
        pass


    class TheLabApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return MainWidget()


    TheLabApp().run()
```

*TheLab.kv

```
    <MainWidget>:
        Button:
            text: "Hello"
            size: "40dp", "40dp"
            pos: "100dp", "200dp"
```

Comment: I have taken care of that. But the window does not show the button.

Comment: it has to be `thelab.kv` instead of `TheLab.kv`

Comment: the kv file name is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Put in `FloatLayout`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class MainWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass


class TheLabApp(App):
    pass


TheLabApp().run()
```

Comment: Doesn't need a floatlayout to show the button.

Answer (score 0):

for linux users the .kv file has to be in lowercase

if you name the class as
`class TheLabApp(App):`

then the .kv file has to be

`thelab.kv`

Atleast this worked for me